# What are < symbols in Crystal classes used for?

Tags: crystal-lang

What is the `<` symbol in this class and what is its purpose?

```
class CommentSerializer < BaseSerializer
  def initialize(@comment : Comment)
  end

  def render
    {body: @comment.body}
  end
end
```

https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.33.0/Class.html#T.class):BoolforallT-instance-method

Not sure if this is correct or what it means:

> Returns whether this class inherits or includes other.

Comment: `<` means less than, it also means "inherits from" it also can mean "descends from" when using generics in macros.

Comment: Quite a basic question I see now. Just never used classes in JavaScript. Had always used a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<` signifies inheritance. You should read `class CommentSerializer < BaseSerializer` as the class `CommentSerializer` being *derived from* or *based on* `BaseSerializer`. `CommentSerializer` *inherits* the behaviors of `BaseSerializer`: it gets all of its instance variables and all of its methods without having to write them out again. This idea of inheritance is common to all object oriented programming languages, as it is a useful way to express code reuse: all the things inside `BaseSerializer` remain the same in its subclasses, and each subclass adds stuff/makes changes to tailor that generic behavior to a specific purpose.

The `<` symbol you found was a method that *tests* for this relationship. It's an expression, and is not the same thing as the `<` in the declaration (which is built into the syntax). The idea is that you defined `CommentSerializer < BaseSerializer`, and so the test `CommentSerializer < BaseSerializer` will return true. The reuse of the symbol is a mnemonic.

[Language reference](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/inheritance.html)

Comment: Cheers! I will read up on that and read about inheritance in OOP.

Comment: It can be helpful to think of a superclass as "higher" or "above" the subclass. In the abstract sense, it is "higher" in abstraction. In this case, `BaseSerializer` is the superclass and `CommentSerializer` is the subclass, so `CommentSerializer` is "below" `BaseSerializer`. This is why the "less than" symbol is used.

Comment: Coming from JavaScript classes were introduced in ES6 so I learned that this week. I was able to understand how classes and superclasses work in Crystal. Looked into structs also, another thing JS doesn’t have in its main language.