# In Crystal, what's the difference between inheritance and inclusion?

Tags: crystal-lang

In most of the Crystal docs, class inheritance is used, with `<` syntax (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61053311/2954547).

However, `HTTP::Handler` says that custom handlers must *include* the `HTTP::Handler` module and not *inherit from* some class.

I can't find a description in the Crystal docs of what `include`-ing a module is supposed to do, or how it differs from `<`-inheritance of classes.

What does it mean when a class *includes* a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inclusion is also a form of inheritance.

The main difference is really that extending a type is limited to exactly one parent. The extension inheritance graph of the entire program is a tree.
In contrast, a type can include multiple modules. And there can be multiple include inheritance paths between two types.

Comment: Is it fair so summarize that `extend` inherits from another *class*, while `include` inherits from a *module*?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I assumed this was already established in the question.
Although there needs to be some caution: Class inheritance via `<` should not be confused with `extends`. That's a different keyword and essentially inheritance from a module's meta class.

Comment: Hm, that warrants a separate question I think.

Answer (score 0):

The description of inclusion is buried in the "Module" specification: https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/modules.html

The example in the docs page is:

> An include makes a type include methods defined in that module as instance methods:

```rb
module ItemsSize
  def size
    items.size
  end
end

class Items
  include ItemsSize

  def items
    [1, 2, 3]
  end
end

items = Items.new
items.size # => 3
```

There is also the related `extend`, which includes module members as class-level members and not instance-level members.

This is a useful way to define *mixins* or other namespaces, that are not meant to be instantiated as objects.