# Crystal: inheritance vs inclusion vs extension

Tags: crystal-lang

*I asked a more limited version of this question at [In Crystal, what's the difference between inheritance and inclusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67047478/2954547), but I think I (and other readers) would benefit from a more comprehensive answer.*

What are the differences between **inheritance** (with `<`), **inclusion** (with `include`), and **extension** (with `extend`) in Crystal classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

#### Class inheritance

Inheritance with `<` duplicates instance attributes, instance methods, class attributes, and class methods from the inherited *class* into the current class.

Modules cannot inherit or be inherited.

```
class A
  # Equivalent to `@@foo = 1` with corresponding getter and setter class methods
  @@foo = 1

  # Equivalent to `@foo = ` with corresponding getter and setter instance methods
  @foo = 2
end

class B < A
end

pp A.foo == B.foo  # true
pp A.new.foo == B.new.foo  # true
```

The value of a class attribute in the superclass is not the same as the value in the subclass, but the types will be the same.

```
class C
  class_property foo = 1
end

class D < C
end

D.foo = 9
pp C.foo == D.foo  # false
```

A class can inherit from exactly one class.

#### Module inclusion

`include` duplicates instance attributes and instance methods from the included *module* into the current class or module.

Classes cannot be included.

It is possible to define class attributes and class methods on modules, but these are *not* duplicated by inclusion; they are ignored.

```
module BirdHolder
  # Ignored by `include`
  class_property bird = "123"
  property bird = "456"
end

class Thing
  include BirdHolder
end

pp Thing.new.bird  # "456"
pp Thing.bird  # Error: undefined method 'bird' for Thing1.class
```

A type (module or class) can include any number of modules.

#### Module extension

`extend` duplicates instance methods from the included *module* into the current class or module, but as class methods.

Classes cannot be extended.

Class attributes and class methods from the extended module are ignored.

```
module Talkative
  # Ignored by `extend`
  @@stuff = "zxcv"

  # Ignored by `extend`
  def self.say_stuff
    puts "stuff"
  end

  def say_stuff
    puts @@stuff
  end
end

class Thing
  extend Talkative
  @@stuff = "asdf"
end

Thing.say_stuff  # "asdf"
```

Note that `@@stuff` in the definition of the `Talkative` module refers to the *class attribute of the extending class*, not to the class attribute of `Talkative` itself.

It is not possible to extend a module that defines instance methods. This results in a compilation error.

A type (module or class) can extend exactly one module.

### References

This information is based on:

- [Crystal Reference: Classes and Methods](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/classes_and_methods.html)
- [Crystal Reference: Modules](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/modules.html)
- [Answer to my previous question by Johannes Müller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67062744/2954547)
- Assistance from users in the `crystal-lang/crystal` Gitter chatroom.

This answer is valid as of Crystal 1.0.0

Comment: I only quickly skimmed the answer, but "A type (module or class) can extend exactly one module." seems to be incorrect. Multiple extends are possible.

Comment: It is really great to get such explanation from someone who just explored the problem space =) Maybe you could help improve the documentation at https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal-book/ with this? A PR there would also make it easier to iron out the details.

Comment: @JohannesMüller I got the "can extend exactly one module" part from your post! Did I misunderstand? Also yes I would be happy to help w/ the docs there, although I'm not sure where this would belong in the language reference.